# Loop to create form

Tags: php, for-loop

I want to create a for loop to create 10 text inputs with unique names/ids. Currently I am using the following code.

```
<?php 
    for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) { 
        echo "<input name='person'" + $i + "' type='text' id='person'" + $i + "' /><br />";
    }
?>
```

Now it just outputs the number in the loop, but doesn't output any inputs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Concatenation in php is done via '.' and not '+'

```
<?php 
    for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) { 
        echo "<input name='person". $i . "' type='text' id='person" . $i . "' /><br />";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you have a slight error in your HTML attribute syntax, so your quote marks are in the wrong place.

```
<?php 
    for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) { 
        echo "<input name='person" + $i + "' type='text' id='person" + $i + "' /><br />";
    }
?>
```

Comment: I tried that too, but it still outputs just the value of $i, which is just an integer.

Comment: Can you include the HTML output source in your question? The likelyhood is that the HTML output is slightly wrong.

Comment: All it outputs is `024681012141618`

Comment: That's bollocks, only `echo $i;` would do that. Are you sure you're looking at the right code? Put an `echo "Before loop";` before the loop to see if **this** for loop is executed in your code.

Comment: It's definitely that code that I provided. I get the output `For loop!024681012141618` when I put an echo before the for loop.

Comment: Not sure if my syntax is completely correct (haven't touched php in a few years), but try it without using echo and by closing the php tags? `for(etc) { ?> <input name="person<?=$i?>" type="text" id="person<?=$i?>" /><br /> <?php }`